# Protestant explanation of an immortal spirit

Tags: resurrection, death, spirit

Some Christian denominations think that the spirit is not immortal and that death is like sleeping.

When Christ comes back he would resurrect the dead bodies from within the ground (like God made Adam from the earth).

> Revelation 20:5-6 The rest of the dead did not come to life until the
>   thousand years were ended. This is the first resurrection. 6 Blessed
>   and holy is the one who shares in the first resurrection! Over such
>   the second death has no power, but they will be priests of God and of
>   Christ, and they will reign with him for a thousand years.

My questions are -

1. If the spirit is immortal what is the meaning of second death? The first death is death of body. Can the spirit also die?
2. If we go to heaven when we die how does the resurrection work? Would our spirits be taken from heaven and reinserted into a body?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To understand this perspective, it is better to think of "*death*" as "*a separation*", rather than "*a ceasing to exist*".  So, when you "die", your spirit is separated from your flesh, and from this world.

**1)** The [second death](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2021:8&version=NASB) is the ultimate [separation](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Thessalonians%201:9&version=NASB) of (the spirits of) sinners from the presence of God.

**2)** Indeed, (the spirits of) those who are "[resurrected](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2020:6&version=NASB)" will receive new bodies (see below), although we [don't yet know](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20John%203:2&version=NASB) what that will look like, exactly.  But we do know we [won't be raised into the same body](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2015:50&version=NASB) we had here on earth.

> But someone will say, “How are the dead raised? And with what kind of body do they come?”...  All flesh is not the same flesh, but there is one flesh of men, and another flesh of beasts... There are also heavenly bodies and earthly bodies... So also is the resurrection of the dead...  it is sown a natural body, it is raised a spiritual body... Just as we have borne the image of the earthy, we will also bear the image of the heavenly [***-1 Corinthians 15:35-49***](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2015:35-49&version=NASB)

### Q&A

- **Why would a person believe that the spirit lives on when the body is dead?  Answer:** There are many passages (such as [this one](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2016:19-31&version=NASB)) that indicate that prior to the "first resurrection" and "second death", the spirits of those who have died are still "alive".
- **Aren't the spirits of sinners already separated from God?  Answer:** No; not in the ultimate sense.  There is a lot more grace in the lives of sinners right now than people realize.  The separation that comes at the final judgment is too terrible to describe in words.  Clearly sinners are not experiencing the torment of that ultimate separation here on earth.

Answer (score 0):

Death doesn't mean physical decay of human body. It refers to the uncleanness of the soul.

The first death means those who are unbelivers, immoral will not be clothed in white i.e. Holy GOD won't forgive their sins.

"Everyone who conquers will be clothed in white and I will not erase his name from the Book of Life, but I will announce before my Father and his angels that he is mine."- The Revelation Chapter 3 verse 5.

So how to save oneself from the first death?

By following Holy Jesus teachings, we can save ourself from Holy GOD's wrath.

"Many shall be purified by great trials and persecutions..." - Daniel Chapter 12  verse 10.

The below verse from The Revelation Chapter 21 verse 8 suffices second death:

"But cowards who turn back from following me and those who are unfaithful to me and the corrupt and murderers and the immoral and those conversing with demons and idol worshippers and all liars - their doom is in the lake that burns with fire and sulphur. This is the second death."

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE!  When you have a moment, plese take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about us.  This was a good first answer.  I would have been improved with references to official Protestant teachings (church statements, etc.).  Thanks!